# Trigger instead of insert does not work with SqlClient.SqlCommand Object

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, triggers, sqlcommand

I have the following trigger:

```
create trigger cicagInsert
on cicag
instead of insert
as
begin
    insert into cicag(cicagcage, ... several columns)
    select cicagcage, ... several columns modified 
    from inserted
end;
go
```

Additionally I have a stored procedure that performs the insert for this table. The stored procedure works well when I execute it, but it does not work when it is called from my program in vb, it does not insert anything.

I am using a `SqlClient.SqlCommand` object to execute the procedure from my program in vb using the ExecuteNonQuery method, I know the trigger is the problem because when I disable it, the stored procedure works.

The strange thing is that when I debug the method that invokes the ExecuteNonQuery method, it returns a value equal to the numbers rows that is supposed to be affected by the sp, but no row was inserted or updated

Is there something that prevents the trigger to work properly with the `SqlCommand` object?

Please help me, and forgive my bad english

Comment: How are you executing the command? .executeNonQuery? Nothing springs to mind, might be helpful to see the entire Trigger, Stored Proc and VB.Net code

Comment: I added some info, yes I am using the executeNonQuery method. I finally had to remove the trigger and change all the inserts to the table to a stored procedure, at least while I can find a solution. Thanks